# Error with variadiac template: "parameter pack must be expanded"

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

Here's a variadic template function that I've written:

```
template<class Container, class Value, class... Args>
Value& insert(Container& c, Args&&... args) {
    c.emplace_back(args);
    return c.back();
}
```

When I use `insert` like this I'm getting an error:

```
list<int> lst;
int& num = insert<list<int>, int, int>(lst, 4);
```

The error complains about this line in the body of `insert`:

```
c.emplace_back(args); // <= 'args' : parameter pack must be
                      //             expanded in this context
```

What does that mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: You forgot ellipsis: `c.emplace_back(args...);`.

Comment: `Value` should also be the first template argument so that template-argument deduction can be used for the other arguments (i.e `insert<int>(lst, 4);`)

Comment: And you forgot to forward: `c.emplace_back(std::forward<Args>(args)...);`

Comment: A container is required to have a member `value_type`, you can use it to get rid of the `Value` template parameter: `template<class Container, class... Args> typename Container::value_type& insert(Container& c, Args&&... args); insert(lst, 4);`

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The error is due to the missing ellipsis (`...`) after `args` when passing all individual parameters (rather than the parameter pack) to `emplace_back`.

The fixed (and improved) version:

```
template<class Container, class... Args>
auto insert(Container& c, Args&&... args) -> decltype (c.back()) {
    c.emplace_back(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    return c.back();
}
```