# Parameter pack must be expanded in this context

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

I have a complex code using routines like these:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T> class C {
public:
  typedef T Type;
};

class ParamInfo {
public:
  bool value;
};

template <typename T>
void testR(
    std::shared_ptr<typename std::enable_if<
        std::is_same<int, T>::value || std::is_same<double, T>::value, T>::type>
        &param,
    T value) {
  param.reset(new T(value));
}

template <typename jsParamType, size_t paramIndex, typename... jsParamTypes>
bool testV(std::shared_ptr<typename jsParamType::Type> &param,
           ParamInfo &paramInfo) {
  std::cout << param << "\n";

  (*param)++;
  testR<typename jsParamType::Type>(param, 10);
  std::cout << typeid(param).name() << " ++ --> " << *param << std::endl;

  paramInfo.value = true;

  return true;
}

template <typename... jsParamType, size_t... paramIndex>
bool testU(std::tuple<std::shared_ptr<typename jsParamType::Type>...> &params,
           std::vector<ParamInfo> &paramsInfos,
           std::index_sequence<paramIndex...>) {
  bool r[] = {true,
              testV<jsParamType, paramIndex, jsParamType...>(
                  std::get<paramIndex>(params), paramsInfos[paramIndex])...};

  bool res = true;

  for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof...(jsParamType) + 1 && res == true; i++)
    res &= r[i];

  return res;
}

template <typename... jsParamType>
bool testU(std::tuple<std::shared_ptr<typename jsParamType::Type>...> &params,
           std::vector<ParamInfo> &paramsInfos) {
  return testU<jsParamType...>(
      params, paramsInfos, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(jsParamType)>{});
}

template <typename... jsParamType> void test() {
  std::tuple<std::shared_ptr<typename jsParamType::Type>...> params =
      std::make_tuple(std::shared_ptr<typename jsParamType::Type>(
          new typename jsParamType::Type())...);

  std::vector<ParamInfo> paramsInfos(sizeof...(jsParamType));

  bool ret = testU<jsParamType...>(params, paramsInfos);

  std::cout << ret << "\n";
}

int main() {
  // your code goes here

  test<C<int>, C<double>>();

  test<>();

  return 0;
}
```

Although this code compiles and works under MSVC/GNUC++, I get "jsParamType: Parameter pack must be expanded in this context" with my real code at function header

`template<typename jsParamType, size_t paramIndex, typename... jsParamTypes>
    bool testV(std::shared_ptr<typename jsParamType::Type>& param, ParamInfo& paramInfo)`

for this parameter `std::shared_ptr<typename jsParamType::Type>& param`

I try to know what is the reason.
Is necessary `std::forward` in some case?

I know it is not much, but the real code is far to complex to post it.

In my tests, on the real code, without `std::shared_ptr` I don't get the errors, so it must be related to some template evaluation or parameter deduction.

Comment: I don't get any warning with http://cpp.sh/8bkyb or http://rextester.com/HRK7676 and I don't compile with visual studio 2015 update 3.

Comment: "I have a problem in some code I'm not showing you. Here's some code that works. What's the problem?" We are not psychics.

Comment: Right, but the real code is a mixture of Adobe APIs, hundreds of files etc..

Comment: @mike **"in this context"** the error message say itself. We can't help you if you don't give it. Maybe this could help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20588191/error-with-variadiac-template-parameter-pack-must-be-expanded.

Comment: I know this one already, I bang my head since days with this error. I try to provide a code to simulate the issue, weird is that works in most of the cases already and I can't determine the reason for the errors yet.

Answer (score 0):

I will post here my empiric solution, although I am not so sure if it is a compiler bug, I always think of me as a reason for the problem. As the code that produces the problem is too complex to post here (tens of files and dependencies) I will explain my two fixes that made it work:

**Option 1:** Rename `testV` to `testU`

**Option 2:** Keep `testV` name and change its template argumentsjust to differ from the `testU` template arguments, reordering would suffice.

Could be the compiler recursion algorithms that confuse the functions for some reason? I don't know, as it can't be reproduced easily and in some circumstances seem to work without the two solutions above... Well, I don't think this is a true answer, but solves my problem. I am open to any critiques from my fellows programmers here, more experienced than me.